# PostGreSQL load increasing over time, why?

Tags: postgresql, centos

It's a CentOS server (I don't know the specs) and just before anybody states the obvious, keep in mind these mitigating factors:

- the server does a nightly VACUUM job
- all the tables are indexed
- it's pretty much read only (meaning the DBs are not increasing in size)
- the number of queries being ran has been the same every month

Here's a graph of the server load:[alt text http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6352/loady.gif](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6352/loady.gif)

UPDATE (2010/9/15): We never found a server or config cause to this, but our application was optimized and the load is back to acceptable levels at the same usage:

1. Cached some data
2. Found some queries that were rewritten
3. Found some redundant queries

Comment: What processes are taking up the CPU time? This is just showing a high level server load.

Comment: The pgSQL task is taking the CPU load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only should you vacuum, but also vacuum analyze, and reindex (at least once a month), since indexes are not vacuumed.

May I also suggest that your piece of software is just so good that you gain more users over time?

Comment: Good suggestion, we actually beat you to it and we're waiting on new performance graphs to see if the analyze fixes the issue.  Previously we didn't realize we needed to analyze to be sure the indexes were actually active.  I'll vote on your question when we get final word from the server.